# Please explain this python "for" statement: methodList = [method for method in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, method))]

Tags: python, list

I am trying to use introspection to get a list of my objects functions.  I have been reading "Dive into Python", and the aforementioned statement:

```
methodList = [method for method in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, method))]
```

does the trick.  The problem is, I have no idea what it is doing.  To me it looks like some extreme shorthand for looping, testing, and adding elements to a list.  If I am correct, which part of the statement does what?!

In other words, can some one please translate it to English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to look at this:

```
methodList = []
for method in dir(object):  # for every attribute in object
                            # note that methods are considered attributes
    if callable(getattr(object, method)) # is it callable?
        methodList.append(method)
return methodList
```

The construct itself is a list comprehension with a filter.

See: [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir), [`callable()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable), [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr), [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of list comprehensions in Python.

```
[f(y) for y in z]
```

means make a list of elements f(y) for each element y in list z. You can add an optional filte rexpression giving

```
[f(y) for y in z if g(y)]
```

which means make a list of all elements f(y) for elements y in z where g(y) is true.

Translated, this gives

```
[method for method in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object,method)]
```

means make a list of all elements "method" in dir(object) where getattr(object,method) is callable.

Answer (score 2):

It's a list comprehension, equivalent to this:

```
methodList = []
for method in dir(object):
  if(callable(getattr(object,method))):
     methodList.append(method)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I suppose the main thing that is throwing me off is the word 'method'  It seems that it is being used both as a keyword, and a variable name.  when you say "for method in dir" method is a var name.  But as it is used in the getattr function, it is a "keyword" or special word relevant to the getattr function?

Comment: @user `method` (nor `object`) is not a keyword in python

Comment: As far as I know, the only programming language in which `method` is a keyword, is Perl 6 :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your statement spaced out to make it easier to understand:

```
methodList = [method
              for method in dir(object)
              if callable(getattr(object, method))]
```

means:

1. for each `method` (note that `method` here is a variable name) in an `object`,
2. if that `method` is callable (i.e. is an actual method),
3. then put that `method` in the list

If you're familiar with SQL, the part in brackets (called a "list comprehension") is roughly equivalent to:

```
SELECT method
FROM dir(object)
WHERE callable(getattr(object, method))
```

Comment: Hi Gabe.  so this statement [method
              for method in dir(object)
              if callable(getattr(object, method))]
the first use of the word method.... what is that there for?  and could I change it to any arbitrary word, or is there a reason for it being called "method"

Comment: @user You could do `[foo for foo in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, foo))]` and it would work all the same.

Comment: @user609391: Since `method` is just the name of a variable, you could use any valid identifier there.